# Set JavaScript 'this' to an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, object, this

I am looking for a way similar to jQuery's `.attr()` method, where when I click on an element (a `li` tag in this case) I can get the tags attributes.

So my question is, how can I make a function that when an `li` is click, the `this` variable in the function is equal to that DOM element. I am trying to do this without the use of jQuery.

This is what I have that I was thinking would work but it doesn't:

```
function selected(){
    this.title = this.getAttribute("title");
}
```

Assuming there is an element `li` with the attribute title and an onclick with the function `selected()` as the choice.

Comment: How do you assign the onclick?

Comment: Assigned by adding the onlick attribute to the li.

Comment: @Jonah Aliborne  ... Have a look at my answer it should help you out.

Comment: `onclick="selected.call(this)"` will let you do `this.title = this.getAttrib...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` varies based on how a function is invoked.  There are basically 3 patterns of invocation:

- Using the *new* operator e.g. `new Foo()`.  In this case when `Foo` is being executed `this` refers to the new object that is being created.
- Dereferencing a method on an object  e.g. `foo.bar()`.  In this case when `bar` is being executed `this` refers to `foo`.  When a method isn't dereferenced from another object, for example when just invoking a global method, the `this` refers to the global scope, or global object.
- Using *apply* or *call* e.g. `foo.apply(bar)`.  By using *call* or *apply* you can tell the interpreter what `this` should refer to during an invocation.
- As a somewhat special case, `this` refers to the node for event handlers.

In your case if you have a global function called `selected` that is invoked from an event handler such as the following:

```
<li onclick="selected()">
```

then during the invocation of `selected`, since it wasn't dereferenced from anywhere `this` will refer to the global object.  If you want `this` to refer to the object whose event handler is firing then you need to invoke `selected` using the `call` or `apply` pattern and pass the value `this` (which will refer to the node) in as the context parameter.

```
<li onclick="selected.call(this)">
```

I usually try to shy away from using the *call* or *apply* since it isn't obvious from looking at the function what `this` will refer to.  Therefore, in this case I would suggest passing in the node as a parameter.

```
<script>
    ...
    function selected(node) {
       node.title = node.getAttribute('title');
    }
</script>
...
<li onclick="selected(this)">
```

With all this being said, the implementation of your `selected` function doesn't make a ton of sense since it is essentially a no-op (in many cases).

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusing question, but something like:

```
$this = event.target;
$this.title = $this.getAttribute("title") || $this['title'];
```

might work, but check that this is referencing the element.

Comment: @Dr.Molle @ IAbstractDownFactor Ok let me clarify. When I run the code I supplied, i get the error: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getAttribute'. So the issue is that it is not referencing this to the element that is being clicked. If you know jQuery, this is equal to the DOM object being modified when clicked on. I assigned the onclick with an onclick attribute on the li. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the onclick in-line (inside the html), then you would need to handle it like this.

**HTML**

```
<li onclick="selected(this)">Click Me</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function selected(element){
    alert(element.title);
}
```

---

If you assign the onclick from JavaScript then this will work:

**HTML**

```
<li id="myli">Click Me</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function selected(){
    alert(this.title);
}
document.getElementById("myli").onclick = selected;
```

Comment: If I read correctly, the OP really wants to use `this`. In that case, use `selected.call(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the following:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li'){
        alert(e.target.title);
    }
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TmBQM/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function itemSelected(listItem)
    {
        // listItem is your HTMLLIElement
        alert(listItem.title);
    }
</script>
<ul>
    <li title="test1" onclick="itemSelected(this);">Test 1</li>
    <li title="test2" onclick="itemSelected(this);">Test 2</li>
</ul>
```